# Question 2.5.12 on page 23 of Ayman Badawi.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

What I don't understand in this solution is the last line, where he writes the following:
$$b=bb^{Ord(a)}=b^{1+Ord(a)}=(b^2)^{Ord(a)+1}$$
I don't understand this last identity, why is $b^2=b$?

From what does this follow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text

Comment: Which Badawi book are you referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably that's just a mistake. I think what the autor wanted to write is:
$$b^{1+Ord(a)}=(b^2)^{(Ord(a)+1)/2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Probably a typo and they want $2\cdot \frac{m+1}2$ there.

A perhaps simpler argument: The existence part gives us a map $f\colon G\to G$ such that $f(a)^2=a$ for all $a$. Then $f$ is clearly injective, hence bijective, hence surjective. So for any $x$ with $x^2=a$ we have $x=f(y)$ for some $y$ and have $y=f(y)^2=x^2=a$ and hence $x=f(a)$.